# Inno Setup, how to Disable Welcome Page

Tags: inno-setup

How I can disable the welcome page with Inno setup but without disable the next page

My problems its when disable the welcome page, they hide the page who shows the download of additional files

Answer (score 6):

Use the DisableWelcomePage directive.
Without knowing what you use to disable it, I can't say for certain why the next page is being disabled too, but I expect you're either using /silent or ShouldSkipPage without a page check.